# actualizar lo que se muestra en la aplicacion que se alimenta de un txt despues de borrar cierta linea del mismo tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, txt

Hola a la comunidad estoy realizando esta aplicacion

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import messagebox


def populate():
  m=0
  n=0
  with open('txt.txt') as newfile:
    p = (len(newfile.readlines()))
    print(p)
  with open("txt.txt", "a+") as file:
    file.seek(0)
    clientes = [line.rstrip().split("\t") for line in file]
    print(clientes)
    for row in range(p):
        y=Label(frame, text="%s" % row, width=3, borderwidth="1",relief="solid")
        y.grid(row=row, column=0)
        t=clientes[m][n]
        Label(frame, text=t).grid(row=row, column=0)
        m+=1

def onFrameConfigure(canvas):
    '''Reset the scroll region to encompass the inner frame'''
    canvas.configure(scrollregion=canvas.bbox("all"))
def borrar():
    f = open("txt.txt", "r")
    lineas = f.readlines()
    f.close()
    f = open("txt.txt", "w")
    pos = int(borrar_cliente.get())
    if pos >= len(lineas):
        messagebox.showerror(message="NO EXISTE CLIENTE ASOCIADO A ESE NUMERO", title="ERROR")
    else:
        linea = lineas[pos]
        if messagebox.askyesno(message="REALMENTE DESEA BORRAR EL CLIENTE:  " + linea, title="INFORMACION"):
            lineas.remove(linea)
    for linea in lineas:
        f.write(linea)
    f.close()

def borrartodo():
    if messagebox.askyesno(message="REALMENTE DESEA BORRAR TODOS LOS CLIENTES",title="INFORMACION"):
        with open("txt.txt", "w") as file:
            messagebox.showinfo(message="SE BORRARON TODOS LOS CLIENTE",title="INFORMACION")

def validate(*args):
    if borrar_cliente.get():
        borrar1cliente.configure(state="normal")
    else:
        borrar1cliente.configure(state="disabled")



raiz = Tk()
canvas = Canvas(raiz, borderwidth=0, background="#ffffff")
frame = Frame(canvas, background="#ffffff")
vsb = Scrollbar(raiz, orient="vertical", command=canvas.yview)
canvas.configure(yscrollcommand=vsb.set)

vsb.pack(side="right", fill="y")
canvas.pack(side="left", fill="both", expand=True)
canvas.create_window((4,4), window=frame, anchor="nw")


frame.bind("<Configure>", lambda event, canvas=canvas: onFrameConfigure(canvas))
marco7 = Frame(raiz, bd=10, relief="groove",width="100")


borrar_cliente= StringVar()
borrar_cliente.trace_add("write", validate)

listaclinetes= Button(raiz,text= "Listado",command =populate,state="normal", relief="raised", borderwidth=5)
listaclinetes.place(x=200, y=10)
clinteborrar =Label(raiz,text = "Introduzca el numero del cliente que desea borrar",font =("Verdana",10),wraplength=200,fg= "red")
clinteborrar.place(x=200, y=50)
textoborrar= Entry(raiz,textvariable =borrar_cliente,width="23",state="normal",validate="key")
textoborrar.place(x=220, y=100)
borrar1cliente=Button(raiz,text="Borrar un Cliente",command =borrar,state="disable", relief="raised", borderwidth=5,width="18")
borrar1cliente.place(x=220, y=130)
borrartodo =Button(raiz, text="Borrar todos los Clientes", command= borrartodo,state="normal", relief="raised", borderwidth=5,width="18")
borrartodo.place(x=220, y=170)
raiz.mainloop()
```

Y necesito que me ayuden con lo sgt.Esta es una imagen del programa cuando corre[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
esta aplicacion muestra atraves del boton listado una serie de clientes que tengo guardado en un txt de esta forma[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
y en el text box introduzco el numero del cliente que deseo borrar por ejemplo eliminaremos a rosana con el numero 2,,,y lo que necesito es que una ves eliminado automaticamente el listado en la aplicacion se me actualice o cuando le de de nuevo al boton listado,,este resultado no lo estoy obteniendo ,,se me corren los nombres y de un principio hay 12 clientes ,,del 0 al 11 si borro 1 no me aparece habrian 11 clientes es decir del 0 al 10 y no me esta ocurriendo esto,despues de borrar un cliente me sucede lo visto en la sgt imagen[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
,,lo mismo sucede con el boton borrar todos los clientes me los borra en el txt,,pero en la aplicacion me sigue mostrando la lista aunque le de al boton listado de nuevo.,,no se si me hice entender,,lo que quiero es que tanto como borre cierto cliente o como borre todos los clientes el listado de los clientes se me actualice automaticamente en la aplicacion,gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solo tienes que eliminar a los widgets hijos de tu frame `frame`, porque sino estarías creando `Label`s encima de los anteriores.

```
def populate():
    for child in frame.winfo_children():
        child.destroy()
    # el resto de tu código
```

Si quieres que el listado se actualice automáticamente al borrar, puedes llamar a `populate()` al final de tu método `borrar()`:

```
def borrar():
    # todo tu código
    populate()
```

Comment: muchisimas gracias,,,eres un genio,,,con eso todo ok